# What is the proper syntax for using the word 'advocacy'?

Tags: syntax, verbing

> Please let me know if I could provide with any further information that might advocacy in favor of my application.

Is this a correct sentence? Is the word 'advocacy' in a right syntax?

Comment: The word "advocacy" is not correct in that sentence because it's a noun, not a verb. The verb form is "advocate." Also, from my reading of the related definitions, I think advocating has to be done by a person (or group of people), and in your sentence you have "information" advocating. More edits I would make are changing "could" to "can" and removing the word "with." One alternative I thought of is "...information that might advance my application," but I'm not completely happy with that. Can you provide more context? That might help people provide a better alternative.

Comment: I would personally have said "any further information that might support my application", @AndySchweig, but you've made some very good points there.

Answer (score 2):

***[Advocacy](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/advocacy)*** is a noun whose main usages are:

> - ***advocacy (of something)*** (formal) the giving of public support to an idea, a course of action or a belief
>
>   - *He won the Peace Prize for his advocacy of non-violent protest.*
> - ***(specialist)*** the work of lawyers who speak about cases in court. (OLD)

- You appear to be looking for a verb, and ***[advocate](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/advocate_1)***, that refers to a formal, often public, support of something, doesn't suit your context.

I suggest you use verbs like "back or support".